# Brightcove player is not loading in Adobe Connect

Tags: brightcove, adobe-connect

I created a application in flex, a swf files is generated. When I open this file in browser, I can able to view the video. But if I drag and drop this swf file in Adobe Connect sharing pod, no video is getting loaded.

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

There is some unknown problem with brightcove player, when using in adobe connect environment. Hence according to suggestions of my manager,  I used the brightcove API to get the videoIds and played videos using the "VideoDisplay" control in adobe flex. It is working very much fine.